# What is a "kernel" in plain English?

Tags: kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

There are several distinct usages:

- kernel density estimation
- kernel trick
- kernel smoothing

Please explain what the "kernel" in them means, in plain English, in your own words.

Comment: Not to be rude, but isn't this a question that is already answered ad nausea on Wikipedia and the likes? Google gave me the answer within 15 seconds...

Comment: I absolutely hate wikipedia answers for stats. There are rambling, symbolic messes. I am looking for a gem of an answer that can explain the answer in plain English, as I believe that that shows a deeper level of understanding than a math equation. There are many popular "plain English" questions on here, and for good reason.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In both statistics (kernel density estimation or kernel smoothing) and machine learning (kernel methods) literature, kernel is used as a measure of similarity. In particular, the kernel function $k(x,.)$ defines the distribution of similarities of points around a given point $x$. $k(x,y)$ denotes the similarity of point $x$ with another given point $y$.

Comment: This is a nice way of putting it. I am wondering if you can generalize this description to also apply to the kernel of 'kernel density estimation'.

Comment: In a way, yes. One way to understand kernel density estimation is that you approximate the density of a point from some distribution as a weighted average of its similarities with a set of points from the distribution. So the notion of similarity does play a role here as well.

Comment: I understand "kernel" in statistics to be borrowed originally from jargon used in discussion of integral equations.

Answer (score 51):

There appear to be at least two different meanings of "kernel": one more commonly used in statistics; the other in machine learning.

In **statistics** "kernel" is most commonly used to refer to [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) and [kernel smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoothing).

A straightforward explanation of kernels in density estimation can be found ([here](http://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/)).

In **machine learning** "kernel" is usually used to refer to the [kernel trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick), a method of using a linear classifier to solve a non-linear problem "by mapping the original non-linear observations into a higher-dimensional space".

A simple visualisation might be to imagine that all of class $0$ are within radius $r$ of the origin in an x, y plane (class $0$: $x^2 + y^2 < r^2$); and all of class $1$ are beyond radius $r$ in that plane (class $1$: $x^2 + y^2 > r^2$). No linear separator is possible, but clearly a circle of radius $r$ will perfectly separate the data. We can transform the data into three dimensional space by calculating three new variables $x^2$, $y^2$ and $\sqrt{2}xy$. The two classes will now be separable by a plane in this 3 dimensional space. The equation of that optimally separating hyperplane where $z_1 = x^2, z_2 = y^2$ and $z_3 = \sqrt{2}xy$ is $z_1 +  z_2 = 1$, and in this case omits $z_3$. (If the circle is off-set from the origin, the optimal separating hyperplane will vary in $z_3$ as well.) The kernel is the mapping function which calculates the value of the 2-dimensional data in 3-dimensional space.

In mathematics, there are [other uses of "kernels"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28mathematics%29), but these seem to be the main ones in statistics.

Comment: Very nice! I'm going to use your example with the circle to explain kernel methods, as it is the best visualization I met up til now. Thanks!

Comment: Following up Thylacoleo's example using the circle to explain the kernel trick (i don't have enough reputation to add a comment directly to his answer) Was there a simple typo in the equation for the separating hyperplane? and it should be z1 + z2 = r^2, instead of z1 + z2 = 1? Or do I misunderstand? I agree its a nice simple example to illustrate the concept. Thanks. Though the definition of z3 still seems a bit of a mystery, but apparently it doesn't matter for the example centered at the origin.

Comment: Yes there was a typo. Thanks for that Alex. I don't always proofread :-)

Comment: The following video was proposed by an anonymous potential editor as "a great visualisation of what Thylacoleo explained:" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA

Comment: Do we use inner products t o map 2-dimensional data to 3-dimensional?