# PCA: When using eigendecompostion instead of single value decompostion

Tags: pca, svd, eigenvalues

If you want to perform a PCA, I guess that using SVD will always work. Eigendecomposition on the covariance matrix only works when your data is not high dimensional(so n > p). But I'm wonder if there are circumstances in practice where you would prefer eigendecompostion over SVD?

Comment: What is a "use case"?

Comment: Normally "$n$" refers to the number of cases and "$p$" to the number of variables--the "dimension" of the data. Thus the high-dimensional case would ordinarily be understood as $p\gg n,$ rather than $n\gt p.$

Comment: @NickCox I am not sure since I do not know when you would prefer to use it. Maybe it's computationally more efficient?

Comment: @whuber It's what I meant. Maybe it was not written clear enough. Sorry

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the words "use case". I guess "usecase" is a typo for "use case", but the doubt remains. Perhaps you mean: are there circumstances in practice where ...?

Comment: exactly what I meant.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/79043/3277 is what you might want to read. The short answer: both work equivalently (no, you are not right saying that eigen-decomposition is for n>p only), however eigen is generally faster (if n>p) and svd is just slightly more precise.