# Is PCA still done via the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix when dimensionality is larger than the number of observations?

Tags: pca

I have a $20\times100$ matrix $X$, containing my $N=20$ samples in the $D=100$-dimensional space. I now wish to code up my own principal component analysis (PCA) in Matlab. I demean $X$ to $X_0$ first.

I read from someone's code that in such scenarios where we have more dimensions than observations, we no longer eigen-decompose the $X_0$'s covariance matrix. Instead, we eigen-decompose $\frac{1}{N-1}X_0X_0^T$. Why is it correct?

The normal covariance matrix is of size $D\times D$, each element of which tells us the covariance between two dimensions. To me, $\frac{1}{N-1}X_0X_0^T$ is not even of the correct dimensions! It is $N\times N$ matrix, so what would it tell us? Covariance between two observations?!

Comment: The answer to your question is in the circumstance that - as it follows from your posing your task - you don't need the covariance matrix of the columns for itself. You only wanted it as a path to obtain PCs. Right? But the same PCA results can be obtained via eigen of `X'X` and `XX'` (as well as svd of `X` and `X'`). What is called "loadings" in one case will be called "pc scores" in the other and vice versa. Because both are just coordinates ([see, for example](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141755/3277)) and the axes, the "principal dimensions" are the same.

Comment: (cont.) If so and you are free to choose which to decompose - it is wise to decompose that which is to do faster/more efficiently. When `n<p` it takes less RAM and less time to decompose `XX'` since it is of smaller size.

Comment: @ttnphns Great explanation. I see the point now. However, I still have problems going from eigen of `XX'` to the PC. Could you please very briefly show me how? Given that PCs are just eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, I attempted to move from eigen of `XX'` to eigen of the covariance matrix `X'X`, but failed.

Comment: I have to go. Perhaps @amoeba (who is much more agile in algebra than me) or another reader will look in here soon and help you. Cheers.

Comment: @ttnphns: Done :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The covariance matrix is of $D\times D$ size and is given by $$\mathbf C = \frac{1}{N-1}\mathbf X_0^\top \mathbf X^\phantom\top_0.$$

The matrix you are talking about is of course not a covariance matrix; it is called *Gram matrix* and is of $N\times N$ size: $$\mathbf G = \frac{1}{N-1}\mathbf X^\phantom\top_0 \mathbf X_0^\top.$$

Principal component analysis (PCA) can be implemented via eigendecomposition of either of these matrices. **These are just two different ways to compute the same thing.**

The easiest and the most useful way to see this is to use the singular value decomposition of the data matrix $\mathbf X = \mathbf {USV}^\top$. Plugging this into the expressions for $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf G$, we get: \begin{align}\mathbf C&=\mathbf V\frac{\mathbf S^2}{N-1}\mathbf V^\top\\\mathbf G&=\mathbf U\frac{\mathbf S^2}{N-1}\mathbf U^\top.\end{align}

Eigenvectors $\mathbf V$ of the covariance matrix are principal directions. Projections of the data on these eigenvectors are principal components; these projections are given by $\mathbf {US}$. Principal components scaled to unit length are given by $\mathbf U$. As you see, eigenvectors of the Gram matrix are exactly these scaled principal components. And the eigenvalues of $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf G$ coincide.

The reason why you might see it *recommended* to use Gram matrix if $N<D$ is because it will be of smaller size, as compared to the covariance matrix, and hence be faster to compute and faster to eigendecompose. In fact, if your dimensionality $D$ is too high, there is no way you can even store the covariance matrix in memory, so operating on a Gram matrix is the only way to do PCA. But for manageable $D$ you *can* still use eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix if you prefer even if $N<D$.

---

- See also: [Relationship between eigenvectors of $\frac{1}{N}XX^\top$ and $\frac{1}{N}X^\top X$ in the context of PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192372)

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know it has a name! Thanks a lot! I am now confident to use it to speedup my computation.

Comment: My answer assumes that what you want to get is $U$, and perhaps also $S/(n-1)$. If you also want to obtain $V$, then you can compute it via $U^\top X$ after you got $U$. In fact, if your dimensionality is too high, there is no way you can even *store* the covariance matrix in memory, so operating on a Gram matrix is the only way to do PCA.

Comment: This answer is clearer that a lot of expositions I have seen in books. Thanks.

Comment: For purely references purposes: I think the 1969 Technometrics paper of I. J. Good "*Some Applications of the Singular Decomposition of a Matrix*" is one of the first to first reference this fully.

Comment: @amoeba If the eigenvalues of $C$ and $G$ coincide, does this mean the $N+1$th and subsequent eigenvalues of C are zero?

Comment: @MattWenham Precisely.

Comment: @amoeba - thanks for the quick response. Does this also mean that the $N+1$th and subsequent eigenvectors are zero, undefined, or does it effectively not matter because the eigenvalues are zero?

Comment: @MattWenham Well, mathematically any vector from that subspace is an eigenvector. So they exist but are not unique. In practice, it does not matter because we never care about those.