# OLS solution to linear regression via SVD decomposition

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm solving a linear regression problem. In a textbook that I follow, the author says that directly computing the OLS vector:

$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T y$

can lead to problems when $(X^TX)$ is singular or ill-conditioned. Therefore, solving for $\beta$ via SVD is recommended.

If I understand correctly, the problem with inverting $(X^TX)$ via eigendecomposition is that when we take the reciprocal of the eigenvalues $\{\frac 1 {\lambda_1}, \frac 1 {\lambda_2}, \ldots\}$ if the matrix is singular (or close) some of those eigenvalues will be close to zero, making its reciprocal explode in size (By the way, am I correct here?).

But doesn't the same thing happen with the SVD decomposition?

$\beta = V\Sigma^{-1}U^T$

Since $\sigma_i = \sqrt {\lambda_i}$ and we still need to take the reciprocal of $\sigma_i$, won't we have the exact same problem?

Thanks

Comment: You don't take reciprocals of the zero singular values--you leave them alone.  This is a form of "generalized inverse."  Details are given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159912/919.

Comment: you're totally right: the same thing happens for the singular values. On a computer, they will be small numbers and inverting them would give you a crazy solution. the reason to avoid $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$ is that the *condition number*, which basically measures singular value smallness, for $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$ is larger than that of $\mathbf{X}$. The traditional algorithm to solve least square problems without forming $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$ uses QR decomp of $\mathbf{X}$ (which is what R uses) rather than its SVD.

Comment: @whuber but you still take the reciprocal of the "almost zero" values, right? Doesn't that lead to numerical instability?

Comment: @JohnMadden Ok thanks. It's more stable computing the OLS parameters, but I assume the instability in the estimated parameters is still there, right. I mean, since there's imperfect multicollinearity in the $X$ matrix.

Comment: @Paca Yes if its close enough to numerically singular you're definitely still going to be in trouble, and still need to take the usual measures for perfect colinearity. But if you're not quite perfectly singular, just highly multicollinear, will get better results from doing QR on $\mathbf{X}$ than chol on $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$. Oh and I think SVD is closer to QR. Just no reason to fully diagonalize unless you need to.

Comment: Not right.  The generalized inverse solves the normal equations and it is obtained by *not* inverting the zero singular values.  For numerical reasons, "almost zero" values must be treated as zeros.  Yes, there can be numerical instability: that's inherent in the situation.

Comment: @whuber It's true that if there's exact rank deficiency no decomposition is going to save you in trying to solve that system directly, and using a penalty (or a limit of penalties, like the ginverse) might be appropriate. I'm just stating the fact that I think OP's author was referring to, which is that in the case of an ill-conditioned but not numerically singular system, the SVD/QR is superior to cholesky-based solution to the normal equations, e.g. we should avoid forming the normal equations when possible. See e,g, http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/477577_Chapter_5.pdf

Comment: @John Agreed.  But the question (in its present form, anyway) does not seem to be concerned about such numerical issues.