# PCA with gram matrix produces different results from PCA done using covariance matrix?

Tags: python, pca, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

I was trying PCA on a dataset (#samples=24, #dims=42) via eigendecomposition using numpy. I read that for matrices where the number of features exceeds the number of samples, we should use the gram matrix instead of the covariance matrix ([Is PCA still done via the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix when dimensionality is larger than the number of observations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147880/is-pca-still-done-via-the-eigendecomposition-of-the-covariance-matrix-when-dimen)).

My dataset matrix is $X$ (scaled and centered), and I tried the eigendecomposition once on $X^TX$, and once on $XX^T$. Next, I took the dot product of the original data matrix with eigenvectors:  $X \cdot U$ to get the transformed dataset. Finally I plotted the scatter plots of the transformed data points with the different principal components (the two 5x5 subplots given below). Clearly, the plots look very different.

I want to know the reason for this difference. From what I have read so far, it is not expected to differ much. I am also attaching my code below the figures.

[image: XtX]

The figure above is from the $X^TX$ computation, and the figure below is using $XX^T$:

[image: XXt]

And here is the code...

```
data_stdx=StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
cov_data=np.dot(data_stdx.T,data_stdx) # Gives a 42x42 matrix. Top Figure; doesn't appear to be correct.
#cov_data=np.dot(data_stdx,data_stdx.T) # Gives a 24x24 matrix. Bottom Figure; seems correct.
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(cov_data)
P = eigenvectors.real#*np.sqrt(eigenvalues.real) # Not sure whether to multiply or not!
data_new=np.dot(data_stdx,P)
```