# Different order and signs of eigenvectors when doing PCA via eig() or svd() functions in Matlab

Tags: pca, matlab, svd, eigenvalues

Assume we have a matrix `X = randn(5,3)`. I am doing two things:

**1)** `[S D1 V1] = svd(X);`

**2)** `[V2 D2] = eig(X'*X);`

I am getting:

```
V1 =

   -0.6220    0.5046    0.5987
   -0.6549   -0.7544   -0.0446
   -0.4292    0.4198   -0.7997
```

and

```
V2 =

    0.5987    0.5046    0.6220
   -0.0446   -0.7544    0.6549
   -0.7997    0.4198    0.4292
```

**First question**: How can we interpret the difference between `V1` and `V2`? why some negative values are getting positive and the values are in reverse order?

**Second question**: in principal component analysis, one can compute the principal components (PCs) as `Z = S*D1` or `Z = X*V2`. But in this case `S*D1` is not equal to `X*V2` but `X*V1`. So the PCs are `Z = X*V1` not `X*V2` right?

Comment: The sign of the components is arbitrary and does not matter, see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880. Regarding the order: Matlab's `eig` function tends to order the eigenvectors in the order of increasing eigenvalues; the `svd` function tends to order them in the decreasing order. Hence the order is flipped. One should never rely on the ordering and re-order the components based on the eigenvalues. You can compute `Z` as `X*V1` or as `X*V2` and you will get **the same thing**, just possibly with different signs and in different order.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact by using `eig`, `V2` is probably to be complex if the matrix dimension becomes large, whereas with `svd`, `V1` is always real. How can you interpret this fact? Do you think that computing `Z=X*V1` is more preferable?

Comment: SVD is numerically more stable and is usually the preferred way, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87536. Complex values indicate some numerical problems along the way; I would guess that the imaginary part is around the machine precision and so you can write `V2=real(V2)` and it's going to be fine. But it's better to use SVD.

Comment: So in principal component regression(pcr), one can assume: `Y=X*beta + e = S * D1 * V1' * beta + e = Z * V1' * beta + e= Z * alpha + e`. Since `Z = S*D1 = X*V1`. am I right? thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes. But you would usually use only a few components in PCR, not all of them.

Comment: Of course, it will be interesting to discard the least informative components. My last question is: I am wondering why the author of this article entitled: "Use of the Singular Value Decomposition in Regression Analysis" complicated the things in page 5. So why he didn't simply consider that `Z=U*theta` (I am just talking about the article in page 5). It will be interesting if you can integrate your comments as an answer :-)

Comment: Please give a link to the paper, I am not sure which one you are talking about.

Comment: http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~marianar/MI602/material%20extra/svd-regression-analysis.pdf