# Different way to do PCA: overall comparison

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, algorithms, intuition

Given a dataset PCA can be performed via 3 ways:

1. Eigenvalue decomposition
2. Singular value decomposition
3. Non-linear iterative partial least-squares algorithm

Can anyone shed light on comparative study of the 3 ways, what is pros and cons of each way? when to prefer a particular method?

Comment: There actually has been answered questions like this one. Though they don't necessarily refer to a "comparative study". Here is one https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/79043/3277. Search other yourself, please.

Comment: @ttnphns Correct. But, I don't see any question on Non-linear iterative partial least-squares algorithm for PCA and its comparison with say Eigen decomposition. Please mark this as duplicate with link to any such question which discusses Non-linear iterative partial least-squares algorithm vs eigen decomposition. Thanks.