# Is $cos^n(x^2-y^2)$ a valid mercer kernel function?

Tags: kernel-trick, cosine-distance

How to show if $cos^n(x^2-y^2)$ is a valid mercer kernel function if $n$ is positive?

For $cos(x^2-y^2)$ I would assume that:
$cos(x^2-y^2) = sin(x^2)sin(y^2)+cos(x^2)cos(y^2)$
Is a valid mercer kernel with feature map $\phi(x) = (cos(x^2), sin(x^2))^T$

Comment: What's your definition of a valid kernel? Does this satisfy that definition?

Comment: $\cos(.)$ can be negative, is this an issue?

Comment: kernel function is explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/how-to-intuitively-explain-what-a-kernel-is

Comment: I'm not asking what a kernel is *abstractly.* I'm asking what **your definition** is. The word "kernel" is used differently in different places, and knowing what definition **you** use is important.

Comment: It is same as explained in the link.

Comment: The question you've linked asks for intuitive explanations about what a kernel is; none of the answers provide a definition. For example, a Mercer kernel is (1) symmetric and (2) positive semidefinite. Neither of these criteria is expressly manifest on the linked page. Are you asking about Mercer kernels? Or something else?

Comment: Yes you are correct, Mercer kernels.

Comment: I've updated the question description and title to be more specific.

Comment: Mercer kernels are positive semi-definite. This means that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n k(x_i, x_j) c_i c_j \ge 0$ for all finite sequences $x_i, x_j$ and all choices of real numbers $c_i, c_j$.

We can demonstrate (2) is not satisfied if we can find any example satisfying these hypotheses which violates the inequality. Suppose we have $n=2$. Can you choose $x_i, x_j, c_i, c_j$ such that this inequality is violated?