# why kernel methods are called kernel ? where is the intuition?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

One thing i never really understand is why kernel trick is called 'kernel'.

Kernel means:

the central or most important part of something.

synonyms:   essence, core, heart, essentials, quintessence, fundamentals, basics, nub, gist, substance;

what's the connection between above definition and 'make low dimension samples repeatable in high dimension'?

does anyone have any insights here?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/what-is-a-kernel-in-plain-english and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/how-to-intuitively-explain-what-a-kernel-is

Comment: Henry is correct. Please check out both of his links.

Comment: These references explain the various notions of kernels but don't give an answer to the question "why do we call a kernel, a kernel?"